# nodejs http request pending forever

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Im new to nodejs. Just trying to get a http.request function running.

It should listen to the port 3523 on localhost. When people go to the url of http://127.0.0.1:3523/remote?url=www.google.com it should take the visitor to www.google.com

This is the code:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var urlinfo = url.parse(req.url, true),
        params  = urlinfo.query;

    if (req.url.match(/^\/remote/)) {
        console.log("Remote");
        http.request({host: "www.google.com"}, function(response){
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function(chunk){
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function(){
                res.end(str);

            })
        });
    }
}).listen(3523);
```

Now when i enter the url it just pending forever. What did i miss or what did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to redirect, you should be sending status code 302 instead of 200 and please refer [https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to redirect simply use `response.redirect` method

```
if (req.url.match(/^\/remote/)) {
    console.log("Remote");
    response.redirect(req.url);
}
```